# First script using $.ajax and it doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This would be my very first attempt with jQuery and Ajax (and Jacascript in general), so don't shoot me if it's rubbish!

What I want to achieve is: having a page `product.php` where a product is displayed with a nice img and a description. At the bottom putting one `<select>` menù: when an `<option>` is clicked, a jQuery code load the code into `tester.php` passing to it the `value` of the clicked option.
The .php script will analyze the `value` and, based on its value, it will send a query to extract the relative price and img. Now, before doing this, I wrote a really simple code (following the official documentation and some answers here) that should pass a variable `$return` back to the HTML page but I guess the callback it doesn't work and I don't have enough experience in jQuery yet to find the problem and a relative solution.

Can anyone more pro explain me why this doesn't work?
Thanks!

ajaxpost.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuSelect").on("click", function(){
        var str = $("#menuSelect").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tester.php",
            data: { value: str },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="txt" >
</div>

<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">OPT1</option>
  <option value="2">OPT2</option>
</select>
```

tester.php

```
<?php
    $value = $_POST["value"];
    function provaAJAX($value) {
        switch ($value) {
          case "0":
              $return = "First option selected";
              break;
          case "1":
              $return = "Second option selected";
              break;
          case "2":
              $return = "Third option selected";
              break;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    $return = provaAJAX($value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should print the variable to be passed back to the JS :

```
echo $return;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I thought I coul pass a variable back and print it with jQuery but no. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

To pass back to JS you should print the variable
try this: echo $return;

Comment: Hi pavan, your last 4 answers are near to plagiarism.